# Ranking Scores given an array of objectives by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
/*
Given an array of objects: ID|userName|totalScore|competitionRank,
number ID
string userName
number totalScore
number competitionRank
all competitionRanks are set to NULL
give each score a ranking in descending order
*/
```

I am currently not sure if this will pass all edge cases. Also, this seems to be the fastest I can do this, any help on improvements would be awesome. It passed for the test cases I could think of. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
//Initialize data structure
var playerScores = [
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "userName": "person1",
    "totalScore": 230,
    "competitionRank": null
  },{
    "ID": 2,
    "userName": "person2",
    "totalScore": 220,
    "competitionRank": null
  },{
    "ID":3,
    "userName": "person3",
    "totalScore": 250,
    "competitionRank": null
  },{
    "ID":4,
    "userName": "person4",
    "totalScore": 230,
    "competitionRank": null
  },{
    "ID": 5,
    "userName": "person5",
    "totalScore": 250,
    "competitionRank": null
  }
];

playerScores.sort(function(a,b){
  return b.totalScore - a.totalScore;
});

var numTies = 0;
playerScores[0].rank = 1;
for (i = 1; i < playerScores.length; i++){
  if (playerScores[i].totalScore === playerScores[i-1].totalScore){
    numTies++;
    playerScores[i].rank = playerScores[i-1].rank;
  }
  else{
    playerScores[i].rank = i+numTies;
    numTies = 0;
  }
 }

console.log(playerScores);
```

Comment: So you're sorting the objects based on their score? Then what?

Comment: Sorry part of my explanation got cut off, will edit it in now.

Comment: So you're first sorting them descending, then giving each a rank property -- how is rank calculated? Just the index?

Comment: Point of note: If you're going to calculate rankings that are then user submitted, you might want to consider doing that calculation on the back end so it can't be manipulated by a user. Other than that, it looks pretty good. There is always some way to make it marginally better of course and everyone will have a different opinion.

Comment: yeah, it'd be a function to sort and rank ideally. I was just writing this to test it out with given arrays.

Comment: If the first two items are tied and both get rank "1", is the third item supposed to have rank "2" or "3"? I hope you don't mind, but I made your code into a runnable snippet - no changes to your actual code except to  add a `console.log()` to the end to show the results. Anyway, your code seems fine except you're testing `i > 0` inside a loop where that will always be true, and also the line before the loop will crash if the array is empty. Also, within the loop `rank` will always equal `i`, so you don't need both variables.

Comment: third items should be "3" to account for the ties. That's what I had trouble originally with.

Comment: Also if I were to actually use this for an app, I would put everything into separate functions, one to sort, one to rank, and organize for a cleaner code, but wrote this just for this one purpose of creating ranks and testing it out.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in your current code `i + numTies` should actually be `i + numTies + 1`, because the array indices (`i`) are zero-based but the ranks start at 1 (for the test data in the question this didn't cause a problem because the only non-tied item was last).

But you don't need the `numTies` variable at all because a non-tied element's rank will always be the same as its position within the array (+1).

Also, the line before your `for` loop that does the first item will give an error if the array is empty, so you should test for that. And use `var` to declare `i`:

```js
var playerScores = [
  { "ID": 1, "userName": "person1", "totalScore": 230, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 2, "userName": "person2", "totalScore": 220, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 3, "userName": "person3", "totalScore": 250, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 4, "userName": "person4", "totalScore": 230, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 5, "userName": "person5", "totalScore": 250, "competitionRank": null }
];

playerScores.sort(function(a,b){ return b.totalScore - a.totalScore; });

if (playerScores[0]) playerScores[0].rank = 1;
for (var i = 1; i < playerScores.length; i++) {
  if (playerScores[i].totalScore === playerScores[i-1].totalScore) {
    playerScores[i].rank = playerScores[i-1].rank;
  } else {
    playerScores[i].rank = i + 1;
  }
}

console.log(playerScores);
```

If you start the loop from 0 rather than 1, and test for the first element inside the loop, that gives you the option of restructuring the code to use an array iteration function rather than a `for` loop - which would be slower to execute but (arguably) easier to read.

For variety, I've used a ternary operator instead of an `if/else`:

```js
var playerScores = [
  { "ID": 1, "userName": "person1", "totalScore": 230, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 2, "userName": "person2", "totalScore": 220, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 3, "userName": "person3", "totalScore": 250, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 4, "userName": "person4", "totalScore": 230, "competitionRank": null },
  { "ID": 5, "userName": "person5", "totalScore": 250, "competitionRank": null }
];

playerScores.sort(function(a,b){ return b.totalScore - a.totalScore; });

playerScores.forEach(function(player, i, arr) {
  player.rank = i === 0 || player.totalScore != arr[i-1].totalScore
              ? i + 1
              : arr[i-1].rank;
});

console.log(playerScores);
```

Comment: Cool I like it. Didn't realize about how I could just use the iterator for the ranks. Thanks!